# typescript error : doesn't the property on the options type

Tags: typescript

I have a object like:

var options = {title: "", buttons: undefined}

but I want to add a function, like this:

options.open(){...}

typescript reported error info: doesn't the property on the options type,

How can add the function into options?

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = {
    title: "",
    buttons: undefined,
    open: function() {
        console.log("You ran the open() function");
    }
};
options.open()
```

Comment: Quick trigger. Correct answer :)